# Clash among packages?

Tags: tables, color, incompatibility

I am working on a colored table and found clashes in various color packages and finally no color in alternate rows. I have followed suggestions, but nothing seems to be working fine. Below is my sample code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{framed,color}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
% new colours
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, linecolor=orange,outerlinewidth=1, innerleftmargin=15, innertopmargin=15,innerbottommargin=15] 
\textbf{Detailed Test Table} 
\centering 
\rowcolors{1}{}{yellow}
\begin{tabular}{>{\rule{0pt}{.5cm}}c >{\arraybackslash}m{2cm}>{\arraybackslash}m{2cm}>{\arraybackslash}m{6cm} >{\arraybackslash}m{3cm}} 
\hline 

\rowcolor{orange}   \textbf{data} &\textbf{dummy} &\textbf{value} &\textbf{rough} &\textbf{text}\\ 
\hline 
\rowcolor{lightgray}        rsxx  & CreT  & 17603472, 19141561  & twet  & 17603472, 19141561\\ 
                     rs7193xx343  & TrT  & 19597491, 21760908  & twer  & 19597491, 21760908\\ 
                       rxx376333  & CCe  & 2017r3747  & twertw  & 20173747\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{mdframed} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Load only `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` and remove the packages `color,colortbl`. Please load xcolor before `mdframed`. Additional you load `color` twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clashes come as the same package is loaded 2 or more times with different options that clash with  each other. Here `mdframed` loads `xcolor` (due to tikz) but without table option. (`mdframed` also loads `color`). You are loading `color` two times which should be avoided. Also, your definition `\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9}` is wrong. It should be `\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}` (which is again defined twice).

You can get rid of the clashes by one of these methods:

- Use `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` right before the
  `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}`.
- Put `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` before the package that loads
  `xcolor` (here it is `mdframed`)
- Or pass the option to the document itself like
  `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,table]{article}` and do not add
  `\usepackage{xcolor}` (It is already loaded by `mdframed`)

Here is a MWE that uses third method:

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{framed}
%    
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}
%\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9} % This definition is wrong should be {0.9,0.9,0.9}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
% new colours
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, linecolor=orange,outerlinewidth=1, innerleftmargin=15, innertopmargin=15,innerbottommargin=15]
\textbf{Detailed Test Table}
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{lightgray}{yellow}
%\rowcolors[\hline]{3}{green!25}{yellow!50}
\begin{tabular}{>{\rule{0pt}{.5cm}}c >{\arraybackslash}m{2cm}>{\arraybackslash}m{2cm}>{\arraybackslash}m{6cm} >{\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\hline

\rowcolor{red}   \textbf{data} &\textbf{dummy} &\textbf{value} &\textbf{rough} &\textbf{text}\\
\hline
        rsxx  & CreT  & 17603472, 19141561  & twet  & 17603472, 19141561\\
                     rs7193xx343  & TrT  & 19597491, 21760908  & twer  & 19597491, 21760908\\
                       rxx376333  & CCe  & 2017r3747  & twertw  & 20173747\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: You may consider using `booktabs` to draw nice looking rules instead of `\hrule`. Also avoid passing the option `pdftex` to the package `graphicx`.

Comment: Avoid passing the `pdftex` option to `graphicx`.

Comment: @egreg: true. Somehow I missed it as I was concentrating on the main issue. Thanks for noting.

Comment: @HarishKumar Maybe I can draw your expertise and attention to a [closely related problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123071/how-to-color-my-custom-lines-rules-in-a-table-contained-by-mdframed) ?