# Fancy tables in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I am terrible at LaTeX tables. I managed to produce a table, but it looks so basic. How do I make it fancier?

Here is the table's code:

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
         \hline
             Models    & A  & B  & C  & D  \\ \hline
             Model $X$ & X1 & X2 & X3 & X4 \\ \hline
             Model $Y$ & Y1 & Y2 & Y3 & Y4 \\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Wellcome to TeX SX! Please provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE). It is easier for people to run your document and help you.

Comment: I never try to make anything look fancy. I hope to always listen carefully to the information that I want to get across, and let it tell me how it needs to be presented. The only thing I don't like about your table are the vertical bars and horizontal bars, which don't really help. Use spacing instead of bars perhaps, like ` \\[3pt ` instead of ` \\ ` on the first line, and get rid of ` \hline ` and ` | `.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Besides using `booktabs`, you can use either `colortbl` or `xcolor` (with the option `[table]` to color the tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
 \begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*5l}    \toprule
\emph{name} & \emph{foo} &&&  \\\midrule
Models    & A  & B  & C  & D  \\ 
\rowcolor{blue!50} Model $X$ & X1 & X2 & X3 & X4\\ 
\rowcolor{green!50} Model $Y$ & Y1 & Y2 & Y3 & Y4\\\bottomrule
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another method is somewhat automatic:

```
\rowcolors{<starting row>}{<first color>}{<second color>}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
 \begin{document}

\rowcolors{3}{green!25}{yellow!50}
\begin{tabular}{ *5l }    \toprule
\emph{name} & \emph{foo} &&&  \\\midrule
Models    & A  & B  & C  & D  \\ 
Model $X$ & X1 & X2 & X3 & X4\\ 
Model $Y$ & Y1 & Y2 & Y3 & Y4\\\bottomrule
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Refer to the documentation of `xcolor` at [texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net) for more details.

Comment: Thank you @Harish. It works in a separate document, but does not work in my own document even though I added the packages.  It says "! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor". Any idea why?

Comment: @Günal To prevent that add `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` before `\documentclass{article}` and remove `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. This happens because some package you are using (may be tikz?) also loads `xcolor` but with different or no options. refer to this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52978/11232 for some more details.

Comment: Perfectly works. Cheers

Answer (score 20):

You shouldn't use vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
 \begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} *5l @{}}    \toprule
\emph{name} & \emph{foo} &&&  \\\midrule
Models    & A  & B  & C  & D  \\ 
 Model $X$ & X1 & X2 & X3 & X4\\ 
 Model $Y$ & Y1 & Y2 & Y3 & Y4\\\bottomrule
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

it is a bit tricky if one has on the left and right no `\tabcolsep` which looks better to me, but want to color the lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}>{\kern\tabcolsep}l<{\kern\tabcolsep}}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 \begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l L L L @{} >{\kern\tabcolsep}l @{}}    \toprule
\emph{name} & \emph{foo} &&&  \\\midrule
Models    & A  & B  & C  & D  \\ 
\rowcolor{black!20}[0pt][0pt] Model $X$ & X1 & X2 & X3 & X4\\ 
\rowcolor{black!40}[0pt][0pt] Model $Y$ & Y1 & Y2 & Y3 & Y4\\\bottomrule
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Herbert. It looks brilliant. Can you please also tell me how to paint the rows? I want the colors of the rows Model X and Model Y to be different.

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 16):

Use `booktabs` package. The documentation discuss how to produce nicer tables.

- Don't use vertical lines
- Don't use unnecessary horizontal lines
- Take out the extra space at right and left of table with `@{}`

You can read more in this [guide](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *4c @{}}
\toprule
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{Models}    & A  & B  & C  & D  \\ 
\midrule
 Model $X$ & X1 & X2 & X3 & X4 \\ 
 Model $Y$ & Y1 & Y2 & Y3 & Y4 \\ \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: my table ends up before my text with your solution

Comment: @David天宇Wong: Can you elaborate more the comment? This answer has nothing to do with the position of the table in the text.

Comment: I removed 
\begin{table} and no problems

Comment: @David天宇Wong, `table` makes the `tabular` to float, so LaTeX place it where it thinks is better to pagniate the text.

Answer (score 9):

+1 for the other answers- you can get some fancy *input* by using the [`pgfplotstable`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplotstable.pdf) package

[image: screenshot]

You can colour the rows if you like- see the documentation for more details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

% global settings
\pgfplotstableset{
    every head row/.style={
    before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={
    after row=\bottomrule},
    col sep = &,
    row sep=\\,
    string type,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{
 Models    & A  & B  & C  & D  \\ 
 Model $X$ & X1 & X2 & X3 & X4 \\ 
 Model $Y$ & Y1 & Y2 & Y3 & Y4 \\
 Model $Z$ & Z1 & Z2 & Z3 & Z4 \\
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, a proposal using the excellent `tabularray` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Example of table with \texttt{tabularray}.}
  \label{tab:example}
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={lllll},
      row{1}={font=\bfseries},
      column{1}={font=\itshape},
      row{even}={bg=gray!10},
    }
              & A  & B  & C  & D  \\
    \toprule
    Model $X$ & X1 & X2 & X3 & X4 \\
    Model $Y$ & Y1 & Y2 & Y3 & Y4 \\
    Model $Z$ & Z1 & Z2 & Z3 & Z4 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]