# Fancy colored array in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, tabularx, tcolorbox

I would like to reproduce these kinds of arrays in Latex (probably with `tcolorbox`) but I have no idea how to achieve this. So is there a way to make these kinds of tables ?

[image]

Note : I would like the switching between colors from one line to another to be automatic.

Comment: I think with `colortbl` is enough, there's no need for `tcolorbox` unless you want to add frames. Some examples here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples?lq=1, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94032/fancy-tables-in-latex?rq=1

Comment: With `colortbl` it can be made automatic.

Comment: See also these slides on how to make good tables: https://speakerdeck.com/cherdarchuk/clear-off-the-table

Comment: Here is the gif version http://darkhorseanalytics.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ClearOffTheTableMd.gif

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `colortbl` package is enough to create such tables as the other commentors wrote.
The following example code uses `\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}` where the option `table` loads `colortbl`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,ignoreheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\arraycolor}[1]{\protect\leavevmode\color{#1}}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\columncolor{blue!50!white}}c}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{LightGoldenrod}}c}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\columncolor{FireBrick!50}}c}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\columncolor{Gray!42}}c}

\begin{document}    

\begin{center}
\sffamily
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\rowcolors[\hline]{3}{.!50!White}{}
\begin{tabular}{A|B|C}
  \multicolumn{3}{D}{\bfseries Example table}\\
  \rowcolor{.!50!Black}
  \arraycolor{White}\bfseries First column &
  \arraycolor{White}\bfseries Second column&
  \arraycolor{White}\bfseries Third column\\
  1 & A & E\\
  2 & B & F\\
  3 & C & G\\
  4 & D & H\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... But this code does not include any reference to colortbl ?

Comment: @VincentFourmond Not directly, but via `\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}` where the option `table` loads `colortbl`

Comment: Ah, OK. That may be worth adding to the answer to avoid confusing other readers ?

Comment: @VincentFourmond Done.

Answer (score 5):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` which has built-in tools for the colorful tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}
   [
     columns-width=3cm,
     hvlines-except-borders,
     rules={color=white,width=1pt}
   ]
   {ccc}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{cyan}{1}
  \rowcolors{2}{cyan!25}{cyan!15}
\Body
  \RowStyle[color=white]{}
  First column & Second column & Third column \\
  1            & A             & E            \\
  2            & B             & F            \\
  3            & C             & G            \\
  4            & D             & H            \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\vspace{5mm}
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}[corners=NW,hvlines]{ccc}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{cyan}{1}
  \columncolor{cyan}{1}
  \rowcolors{2}{cyan!25}{cyan!15}[cols={2,3}]
\Body
               & First column  & Second column \\
First line     & A             & E            \\
Second line    & B             & F            \\
Third line     & C             & G            \\
Fourth line    & D             & H            \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]