# Want to make the colorful table in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I make this Table MS Word. But I am interest to make this Table in LaTeX[image]

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet2'
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{rcrrr}
%\toprule
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{} & \textbf{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Development}} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} \\
%\midrule
      & \textbf{License} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Language}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Platforms}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Support}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \textbf{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[1]{*}{\textbf{Linux/Unix, Windows, MAC OSX}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Julius}} & \textbf{BSD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{C}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{_}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\textbf{Prohibits redistributions and commercial use but R \& D allowed}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Windows, Linux/Unix, MAC OSX}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{HTK Book, Active Mailing List}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{HTK}} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{C}} &       &  \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \textbf{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \textbf{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Linux/Unix, Windows, MAC OSX}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Very well documented}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Sphinx}} & \textbf{BSD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{C, JAVA}} &       &  \\
      & \textbf{} &       &       &  \\
      & \textbf{} &       &       &  \\
      & \textbf{} &       &       &  \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \textbf{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} &     \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ISIP ASR}} & \textbf{Public domain (no restrictions)} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{C++}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Windows}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{_}} \\
%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

I generate this code through Excel2LaTeX. But this is not working.

Comment: Maybe, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176220/fancy-colored-array-in-latex/176228#176228 is helpful.

Comment: I am trying to convert it in 4 x 4 but it is not workig anyoe help me. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67586/how-to-create-comparison-tables-in-latex

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to the question but an answer that shows how to draw such a table in ConTeXt.

I find ConTeXt to be much better suited for such tables than LaTeX. ConTeXt allows for a nice separation of content and presentation. For example, the basic structure to achieve the requested layout is:

```
\startsetups table:style
  % Fill in the details
\stopsetups

\starttext
\startTABLE[setups=table:style]
  \NC           \NC License \NC Development Language \NC Platforms                    \NC Support                       \NC \NR
  \NC Julius    \NC BSD     \NC C                    \NC Linux/Unix, Windows, Mac OSX \NC ---                           \NC \NR
  \NC HTK       \NC Prohibits redistribution and commercial use, but R&D allowed
                            \NC C                    \NC Linux/Unix, Windows, Mac OSX \NC HTK Book, Active mailing list \NC \NR
  \NC Sphinx    \NC BSD     \NC C, Java              \NC Linux/Unix, Windows, Mac OSX \NC Very well documented          \NC \NR
  \NC ISIP ASR  \NC Public Domain (no restrictions)
                            \NC C++                  \NC Windows                      \NC ---                           \NC \NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

Without any modifications of `table:style`, the default output is:

[image]

To get the desired output, start by setting the font style (bold) and alignment (horizontally and vertically middle aligned), and add some offset around the cells. This can be done by:

```
\startsetups table:style
  \setupTABLE[align={middle,lohi}, foregroundstyle=bold, offset=0.25ex]
\stopsetups
```

which gives

[image]

Finally, set the background color for cells using:

```
  \setupTABLE[background=color, framecolor=white]
  \setupTABLE[row][odd] [backgroundcolor=rowcolor1]
  \setupTABLE[row][even][backgroundcolor=rowcolor2]

  \setupTABLE[row][first][backgroundcolor=headercolor,foregroundcolor=white]
  \setupTABLE[column][first][backgroundcolor=headercolor,foregroundcolor=white]
```

which gives:

[image]

The complete code is

```
\definecolor[rowcolor1]  [h=E6EED6]
\definecolor[rowcolor2]  [h=CDDDAC]
\definecolor[headercolor][h=9BBB58]

\startsetups table:style
  \setupTABLE[align={middle,lohi}, foregroundstyle=bold, offset=0.5em]

  \setupTABLE[background=color, framecolor=white]
  \setupTABLE[row][odd] [backgroundcolor=rowcolor1]
  \setupTABLE[row][even][backgroundcolor=rowcolor2]

  \setupTABLE[row][first][backgroundcolor=headercolor,foregroundcolor=white]
  \setupTABLE[column][first][backgroundcolor=headercolor,foregroundcolor=white]
\stopsetups

\starttext
\startTABLE[setups=table:style]
  \NC           \NC License \NC Development Language \NC Platforms                    \NC Support                       \NC \NR
  \NC Julius    \NC BSD     \NC C                    \NC Linux/Unix, Windows, Mac OSX \NC ---                           \NC \NR
  \NC HTK       \NC Prohibits redistribution and commercial use, but R&D allowed
                            \NC C                    \NC Linux/Unix, Windows, Mac OSX \NC HTK Book, Active mailing list \NC \NR
  \NC Sphinx    \NC BSD     \NC C, Java              \NC Linux/Unix, Windows, Mac OSX \NC Very well documented          \NC \NR
  \NC ISIP ASR  \NC Public Domain (no restrictions)
                            \NC C++                  \NC Windows                      \NC ---                           \NC \NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

Comment: +1 This is clearly nice. I hope some day this comes to the LaTeX world (or may be I end up in ConTeXt).

Comment: @Aditya I am working in LaTeX. Please share the full code with LaTeX packages. Also I find the link which I am sharing here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67586/how-to-create-comparison-tables-in-latex

Comment: @LaTeXKhan, as I said, this is a context solution, not a latex one. This is the _full_ code.

Answer (score 2):

I you think can use several commands to specify the cell background color, row color or even column color, you can set the color on RGB or HTML. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rcrrr}
\rowcolor[HTML]{32CB00} % Fill color of the entire row
something & something & something & something & something \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{67FD9A} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} something & something  & something & something & something \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{9AFF99} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} something & something & something & something & something \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{67FD9A} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}something & something & something & something & something
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Make sure you have xcolor on your preamble with the options "table" and "xcdraw" . The \rowcolor[]{} command fills up the whole row, while the \cellcolor[]{}  colors only the cell where you put it.

Comment: Error \rowcolor[HTML]{32CB00} undefined control sequence

Comment: Please, make the snippet into a full compilable code.

Comment: Yeap, had to add two options to the xcolor package, already fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @Tepexic how i change the color. Check out this link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67586/how-to-create-comparison-tables-in-latex