# Undefined Extra text coming list of tables and list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

[image][image]There is some issue in my list of figure and list of tables. It appears as
Table 1.1 table Name of table
I am unable to understand from where this extra 'table' is coming after Table 1.1. Also this extra text overlaps with the caption which follows. 
In the code there is `\include{front}` - front is my document containing all ack, abstract and stuff. There I put the code `\listoftables`.

Here is the full code

```
\documentclass[11pt,          % font size: 11pt or 12pt
               ms,           % degree:    ms or phd
               onehalfspacing % spacing: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
               ]{ncsuthesis}

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%%------------------------------ Import Packages -----------------------------%%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------%%

\usepackage{booktabs}  % professionally typeset tables
\usepackage{amsmath}%,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}  % better copyright sign, among other things
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}    % filler text
\usepackage{subfig}    % composite figures

%use the following line with plainnat
%\usepackage[super,sort&compress,comma,square,numbers]{natbib} %\cite command %Added by Ortiz
%\usepackage{natbib}

%\usepackage[style=alphabetic,natbib=true,backend=bibtex
%sorting=nyt,firstinits=true,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false]{biblatex} %couldn't get backend=biber to work

%\usepackage{filecontents}

%\bibliography{Ortiz-thesis2}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}


\RequirePackage[
            style=alphabetic,%numeric-comp,%authoryear-comp,%
            sorting=nyt,%ynt                    
            hyperref=true, %    
            firstinits=true,%
            backend=bibtex,
            natbib=true,
            url=false,
            isbn=false,
            maxnames=2, %for et al to be used
            maxalphanames=1, %to avoid printing a + for every et al in the abbreviation
            doi=false]{biblatex}        



\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}
    \renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{}
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{in={}}
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{in={}}
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
    \DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

%\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}} %authoryear          
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\makeatletter

\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\parencite{#1}}


\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{language}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\addbibresource{Ortiz-thesis2.bib}
%\addbibresource{Ortiz-thesisURL.bib}
\addbibresource{YourName-thesis.bib}

 \defbibheading{myheading}[BIBLIOGRAPHY]{
 \chapter*{#1}
 %\centerline{\bf{#1}}
 \markboth{#1}{#1}}

%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} %amssymb and amsfonts cannot be used in conjunction with mdput
%\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
%\usepackage{hyperref}% add hypertext capabilities
%\usepackage{hypernat}% make hyperref and natbib work together
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{verbatim}% multiline commenting
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{balance} 
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx} %eps figures can be used instead
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[format=plain,justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=false,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{abbrevs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify{\DateMark} % after having loaded abbrevs

\usepackage{units} %Needed to solve bug from citation Hydrodynamics in 21/2 dimensions
%see http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=989

\usepackage[sharp]{easylist} %used for brainstorming purposes 
%\usepackage{mathabx} % used for \Asterisk for convolution %conflicts with \widering

%compile on single pass
%\usepackage[backend=biber,...]{biblatex}



%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\newcommand{\ensureoddstart}{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\else\newpage\mbox{}\fi}
%\newcommand{\ensureoddstart}{}


%%%Fancy tables
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94032/fancy-tables-in-latex
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}>{\kern\tabcolsep}l<{\kern\tabcolsep}}



%%%%%%%%%%
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} %may violate ETD
%Usage http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-activate-subsubsubsection-in.html
%\section{} % level 1
%\subsection{} % level 2
%\subsubsection{} % level 3
%\paragraph{} % level 4 - equivalent to subsubsubsection
%\subparagraph{} % level 5

%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\usepackage{placeins}
%De�fines a \FloatBar�rier com�mand, be�yond which floats may not pass; use�ful, for ex�am�ple, to en�sure all floats for a sec�tion ap�pear be�fore the next \sec�tion com�mand.

%%%Hack for centering all figures
%\makeatletter
%\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
%\makeatother

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%%---------------------------- Formatting Options ----------------------------%%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%%

%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------- %%
%% Disposition format -- any titles, headings, section titles
%%  These formatting commands affect all headings, titles, headings,
%%  so sizing commands should not be used here.
%%  Formatting options to consider are
%%     +  \sffamily - sans serif fonts.  Dispositions are often typeset in
%%                    sans serif, so this is a good option. 
%%     +  \rmfamily - serif fonts
%%     +  \bfseries - bold face
%\dispositionformat{\sffamily\bfseries}   % bold and sans serif
\dispositionformat{\bfseries}            % bold and serif

%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------- %%
%% Formatting for centered headings - Abstract, Dedication, etc. headings
%%  This is where one might put a sizing command.
%%  \MakeUppercase can be used to typeset all headings in uppercase.
\headingformat{\large\MakeUppercase}   % All letters uppercase
%\headingformat{\large}                % Not all uppercase
%\headingformat{\Large\scshape}        % Small Caps, used with serif fonts.

%% Typographers recommend using a normal inter-word space after
%% sentences. TeX's default is to add an wider space, but \frenchspacing
%% gives a normal spacing. Comment out the following line if you prefer
%% wider spaces between sentences.
\frenchspacing


%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------- %%
%%  Optional packages
%%    A number of compatible packages to improve the look and feel of
%%    your document are available in the file optional.tex 
%%    (For example, hyperlinks, fancy chapter headings, and fonts)
%% To use these options, uncomment the next line and see optional.tex
\include{optional}
%solve bug from fancyhdr in optional
%http://nw360.blogspot.com/2006/11/latex-headheight-is-too-small.html
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%%---------------------------- Content Options -------------------------------%%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Size of committee: 3, 4, 5, or 6 -- this number includes the chair
\committeesize{3}

%% Members of committee
%%  Each of the following member commands takes an optional argument
%%   to specify their role on the committee.
%%  For co-chairs, use the commands:
%%      \cochairI{Doug Dodd}
%%      \cochairII{Chris Cox}
%%
\chair{Dr. Mesut Baran}
\memberI{Dr. David Lubkeman}
\memberII{Dr. Ning Lu}
%\memberIII{Chris Cox}   % unnecessary if committeesize=3
%\memberIV{Fred Ford}    % unnecessary if committeesize=3 or 4
%\memberV{Edna Everitt}  % unnecessary if committeesize=3, 4, or 5


%% Student writing thesis, \student{First Middle}{Last}
\student{Shashwat}{Singh} % a full middle name
%\student{John M.}{Smith} % a middle initial

%% Degree program
\program{Masters of Science - Electrical Engineering}

%% Thesis Title
%%  Keep in mind, according to ETD guidelines:
%%    +  Capitalize first letter of important words.
%%    +  Use inverted pyramid shape if title spans more than one line.
%%
%%  Note: To break the title onto multiple lines, use \break instead of \\.
%\thesistitle{A North Carolina State University Sample \LaTeX{} Thesis \break 
%with a Title So Long it Needs a Line Break}
\thesistitle{Cost Benefit Analysis of FREEDM System}

%% Degree year.  Necessary if your degree year doesn't equal the current year.
%\degreeyear{1995}


%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%%---------------------------- Personal Macros -------------------------------%%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------%%

%% A central location to add your favorite macros.

%% A few examples to get you started.
\newcommand{\uv}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{\hat{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\bo}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{\Omega}}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Eq.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Fig.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\del}{\nabla}
\renewcommand{\exp}[1]{e^{#1}}
\newcommand{\Conv}{\mathop{\scalebox{1.5}{\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$\ast$}}}}%


\usepackage{color}
%\newcommand{\NEW}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\NEW}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\COMMENT}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}


\newcommand{\NOTER}[1]{\textcolor{orange}{#1}}
\newcommand{\NOTEC}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\NOTEK}[1]{\textcolor{magenta}{#1}}

\newcommand{\mum}{\ensuremath{{\mu}\text{m}}}

%This makes it so that you can add short paths in your .tex by including the folders where you store your images in the search path
\graphicspath{{./Chapter-1/figs/}{./Chapter-2/figs/}{./Chapter-3/figs/}{./Chapter-4/figs/}}%{./Chapter-5/figs/}{./Chapter-6/figs/}}


%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
\usepackage{calc}
%% Capital letter height
\newlength{\chaptercapitalheight}
\settoheight{\chaptercapitalheight}{D}
\newlength{\chapterfootskip}
\setlength{\chapterfootskip}{\chaptercapitalheight}
\addtolength{\chapterfootskip}{2\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\chapterfootskip}{0.5ex}  % A little extra space to ensure there are 2 full double spaced lines
%\def\chapterfootskipnum{\chapterfootskip}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}

%\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\centering\ncsu@headingformat}


%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47184/height-of-figure-caption-textheight
\newlength\graphht
\newcommand\calculategraphicstargetheight[1]{%
     \setlength\graphht{\textheight 
                       -\parskip
                       -\abovecaptionskip -\belowcaptionskip
                       -(12pt * #1) % assuming baselineskip of 12pt in caption
                       -\chapterfootskip
                       }}

%\usepackage{titlesec}

%landscape support in fancyhdr from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/how-to-translate-and-rotate-the-heading-of-landscaped-pages
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\fancypagestyle{lscapedplain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[outer sep=1cm,above,rotate=90] at (current page.east) {\thepage};}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
\frontmatter

\include{front}

%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
\mainmatter


\pagestyle{fancy}
\newgeometry{margin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,footskip=\chapterfootskip, includehead, includefoot}
\include{Chapter-1/Chapter-1}
\include{Chapter-2/Chapter-2}
\include{Chapter-3/Chapter-3}
\include{Chapter-4/Chapter-4}
%\include{Chapter-5/Chapter-5}
%\include{Chapter-6/Chapter-6}
%\restoregeometry


%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%%  Bibliography 

%%  You can use the bibitem list.
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{1}
M.E. Baran (2011)
\newblock {\it Smart distribution system research and education at the FREEDM Systems Center},
Power and Energy Society General Meetings, San Diego, CA.
\end{thebibliography}

%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}%plainnat is necessary to enable the use of citet. Natbib style file.
%\bibliography{Ortiz-thesis2}
%\ensureoddstart
\begin{spacing}{1}
 \setlength\bibitemsep{11pt} %22pt = 2*11pt, where fontsize is 11pt
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\uppercase{\bibname}}} %\textorpdfstring and \uppercase needed due to hyperref package http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=16601
 %\vspace{-0.5in}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bf\filcenter
}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{11pt}{\bf\filcenter}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-0.5in-9pt}{22pt}

\printbibliography[heading=myheading]
\end{spacing}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}


%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
% Appendices
%\ensureoddstart
\restoregeometry
\appendix
\newgeometry{margin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,footskip=\chapterfootskip, includehead, includefoot}


\include{Appendix-A/Appendix-A}

\restoregeometry

%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%\ensureoddstart
\backmatter


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I am at least as unable as you to see where it comes from. But may be a minimal example would help ;o)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response!! I put in a snap of how it looks like.

Comment: I had understood. The problem is to see a code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I added a snap of the code too.

Comment: An image of  the code is useless. We can't compile an image to see what happens. Furthermore, most probably, the issue comes from  the preamble.

Comment: I put in the full code from the template I am using. There are probably lot of things in there which are useless but me being new to latex don't know which ones to remove.

Comment: OK. I've made the code readable. F.y.i., to insert code properly, select it and click on the pair of braces in the tool bar at the top of the editing window. I'll  try to see where the problem is, but probably it's a matter of incompatible packages.

Comment: Your example is not minimal indeed. Try to cancel out definitions, packages and options until the error disappers. Then you have a candidate for the malfunctioning element. Do this until you are sure that only the things are in your example that really cause the wrong behaviour. Help your helpers!

Comment: You don't need to know LaTeX to create a minimal example. It is just a mechanical process: take stuff out, compile; does the problem disappear? if so, put the last stuff back in and repeat with different stuff / if not, leave it out and repeat with different stuff.

Comment: Oh my god, this is an example of `www.messythesistemplates.org` ;-)