# Left align title with blue background, matching a style

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I'm trying to replicate a journal's titling style in LaTeX specifically one that looks like this:

[image]

So far I've got this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{docblue}{RGB}{0,116,178}   
\definecolor{docgrey}{RGB}{166,168,170} 

\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-9em} 

\title{\colorbox{docblue}{\LARGE \textbf{\color{white}{Detection and diagnosis of H7N9 \& MERS-CoV by RT-PCR}}}}
\author{ \textbf{\textsf{J Smith}$\bm{^{1}}$} \\ \color{docgrey}{\textbf{1. Institute, City, Country}}}
\date{}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

I have a few issues:

- None of the title elements are aligned left, I tried using the `flushleft` environment however it caused compile errors.
- `colorbox` causes the title to not wrap correctly and extend over the right margin, it also appears to have slightly less padding too.

How can the above be solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\colorbox` won't break across lines unless you put the contents inside a `\parbox` / `minipage`. Hence you may put the title contents inside a `parbox`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{docblue}{RGB}{0,116,178}
\definecolor{docgrey}{RGB}{166,168,170}

\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-9em} 

\pretitle{\par}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\titlething}{\colorbox{docblue}{%
\LARGE \bfseries\textcolor{white}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{Detection and diagnosis of H7N9 \& MERS-CoV by RT-PCR}}}}
\title{\titlething}
\posttitle{\par}
\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}}
\author{ \textbf{\textsf{J Smith}$\bm{^{1}}$} \\ \color{docgrey}{\textbf{1. Institute, City, Country}}}
\postauthor{\end{flushleft}}
\date{}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Another approach using `tcolorbox` (things can get fancier here ;-)...):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{docblue}{RGB}{0,116,178}
\definecolor{docgrey}{RGB}{166,168,170}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-9em}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\pretitle{\par}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\titlething}{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[   %% Adjust the following parameters at will.
        left=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt,
        colback=docblue,
        colframe=docblue,
        width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
        enlarge left by=0mm,
        boxsep=5pt,
        arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
        ]
        \LARGE \bfseries\textcolor{white}{Detection and diagnosis of H7N9 \& MERS-CoV by RT-PCR}
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\title{\titlething}
\posttitle{\par}
\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}}
\author{ \textbf{\textsf{J Smith}$\bm{^{1}}$} \\ \color{docgrey}{\textbf{1. Institute, City, Country}}}
\postauthor{\end{flushleft}}
\date{}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works and it compiles a document that looks just fine but it does give me the compile error:
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
and
! Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.
both on the line ending the tcolorbox declaration..

Comment: Also any idea how to get the author and institute line to left align?

Comment: Once again everything compiles just fine, but I do get an error '! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.' from the line \definecolor{docblue}{RGB}{0,116,178} interestingly...

Comment: Ben Put `PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}` before `\documentclass{...}` and remove `\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}`

Comment: @Ben Refer: [Clash among packages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52978)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks for your time and effort Harish!

Comment: @Ben You are welcome. Glad it worked.